# ¿Cómo obtener los días de diferencia entre dos campos de fecha en Sql?

Tags: sql

Cordial saludo, estoy intentando obtener la diferencia de días entre dos campos de fecha en Sql, lo estoy intentando hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT A.CREATIONDATE AS FECHACREACION, A.TICKETID AS TICKET, A.ACTUALFINISH AS FECHAFINAL,
CASE WHEN A.CREATIONDATE IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(A.ACTUALFINISH-A.CREATIONDATE)) END AS DIFERENCIADIAS
FROM TICKET AS A
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

FECHACREACION   ___   TICKET     ____FECHAFINAL           _______ DIFERENCIADIAS

2015-12-**03** 09:24:03 __  IN1695  __2015-12-**22** 16:42:18_____    **19**

2016-03-**16** 10:55:42 __IN19931 __2016-03-**18** 14:29:00_____       **2**

2017-01-**02** 19:46:40 __SR96653__2017-01-**05** 07:01:15   ____      **2**

2017-01-**04** 15:31:38 __SR97367__2017-01-**06** 15:35:17_____   **2**

El resultado se encuentra errado ya que en algunas filas hace falta un día y en otras se encuentra bien.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Como ha comentado carmen en su respuesta, deberías usar solo las fechas, no las horas, ya que puede variar. Como estas usando MySQL la idea similar seria algo asi TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,"2009-05-18","2009-07-29")

Comment: Gracias Raúl por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre campos con formato `datetime` puedes obetener la diferencia de días directamente con `datediff`, que tiene en cuenta los días pero no las horas.

```
SELECT A.CREATIONDATE AS FECHACREACION, A.TICKETID AS TICKET, A.ACTUALFINISH AS FECHAFINAL,
CASE WHEN A.CREATIONDATE IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE 
DATEDIFF(A.ACTUALFINISH,A.CREATIONDATE) END AS DIFERENCIADIAS
FROM TICKET AS A
```

Por ejemplo el resultado de la diferencia entre estas 2 fechas es de 3 días:

```
DATEDIFF('2017-01-05 07:01:15','2017-01-02 19:46:40' ) => 3
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta Carmen.